# How can I find the number of items or movies under a specific genre or category in a given data set of movies.

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, counter

I have already completed the separation of the genres for movies now I want to get the number of movies under each each genre, following is my completed code for separating the genres

```
       df['geners_arr']=df['genres'].str.split('|')

       df.head()
       count_lambda=lambda x: len(x)
       df['Genre_count_for_Movie']=df.geners_arr.apply(count_lambda)
       df.head(3)`
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution working nice if no `NaN`s.

More general is [`str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
df['Genre_count_for_Movie']=df.geners_arr.str.len()
```

Or [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html) `|` and add `1`:

```
df['Genre_count_for_Movie']= df['genres'].str.count('|') + 1
```